# load google maps on click

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want to show Google Map, after a link is clicked.

I have tried the following. When the link is clicked, then:

1. Insert `div` after link with id `map`
2. Load Google Maps API with jQuery method $.getScript
3. Add Google Maps to `div` with id `map`

Unfortunately, step 2 does not seem to work. In the JS console I find the error

> ReferenceError: google is not defined

This is my code, except that I have replaced my actual Google API key with the string `mykey` at the line

```
 $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey");
```

Why cant I include the Google Maps API like this? How can I include it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/resources/vendor/jQUery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#showMap').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#showMap').after("<div id='map' style='height: 200px;background-color:#08c;width: 200px;'></div>");

        $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey");

        $lat   = 10.1364;
        $lng   = -80.2514;

        var myLatLng = {lat: $lat, lng: $lng};

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: myLatLng
          });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
          });
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='#' id="showMap">Hello</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works completely fine. Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq19dyt1/). The problem is that you were doing all of your init stuff synchronously, whereas getScript is an async call for an external script.

The second argument of `$.getScript` takes a callback function.

Also, there's no need to add your map div after, just have it there in the first place.

```
$('#show-map').click(() => {
  $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js', () => {

    var myLatLng = {
      lat: 10.1364,
      lng: -80.2514
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: myLatLng
    })

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    })

  })
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Might have worked great 5 years ago, but now the Google API is handled differently, and this code does not work in practice, since there's no Google API Key included. It works in the fiddle because Google knows that's development only, but if you actually run this code, it displays a message "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."