# Avoid loading Google Maps API unless user triggers the map to be displayed

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

So I have a web app that uses Google Maps API to display a map, **but the map is normally hidden from view**, and it isn't needed for every page load. Rather than calling the API for every page load (and loading the map in the background), I only want to call the API and load the map when it's actually needed.

It seems to be bad practice from a bandwidth standpoint, and every page load **could be billed by Google**.

This is how I've had it previously (always loading), which loads as soon as the page is done loading:

```
// Define initMap code here, and then:

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"></script>
```

What is a good way to handle this (preferably a direct-replacement method that can be a single line of code)?

I looked at various code to add this script tag after the fact, but that seems like the wrong approach.

There are some older posts (e.g. [load google maps on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143513/load-google-maps-on-click)), but these are outdated, in that they do not include the API key, which is now required for Google Maps use. They're also multi-line, and are not a direct replacement for the single script tag normally used.

Also, for a simple need like this, I don't like the approach suggested by Google, which requires including another code library. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/programmatic-load-button)

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/programmatic-load-button

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that using jQuery (which I use anyways), the $.getScript option works quite well:

```
$("#user_expand_map_section_button").on("click", function(){
    $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=initSpecifyMap');
});
```

It then only makes the call to the Google Maps API once the user expands the panel / clicks the button / opens the modal, etc.